# How to create tables with hibernate recomandations

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hbm2ddl

I'm relatively new to hibernate technology, and want to create an application with that. I have read that is not recomanded to use "hibernate's creation tabels" option **(hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto)** for a production environment. Does that mean that i need to create first tables and after that my POJOs classes or this recomandations is only for **update** value of **hbm2ddl.auto**?

Thank advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` is recommended for everything else except production. Especially for development. So feel free to use it.

Only when deploying on production use some database scripts to update your schema correctly.